# How to resolve "Unknown column 'description' in 'field list'" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to add single field from many fields to a table:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'description' in 'field list'

Code:

```
INSERT INTO `eys_questions` (`question`, `description`, `answer1`, 
  `checkbox1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`, `answer6`, 
  `answer7`, `answer8`, `answer9`, `answer10`, `image`) 
  VALUES ('This is the question ', 'This is the description', 'This is the answer', '1',
 '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/eys/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: past your db schema for `eys_questions`

Comment: Please add structure of table here. 
Further, I recommend to do in 1-many table instead of saving all answers in one table

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your db table don't have any column with name `description`. Check out the spelling of the column name `description`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the columns on the `eys_questions` table. The error is pretty clear: that table doesn't have a `description` column. You can check the columns on a table with the `desc` (describe) sql command.

In your case `desc eys_questions`. This will show you table information such as column names and types.

Once you've verified column names, you can modify your insert statement accordingly.